# "Emergency stop" error in an original document after copying it (Overfleaf)

Tags: errors, compilation-error

I have a big problem with my LaTeX project. I haven't modified it for 15 hours (worked before !), just copied it to get the same template in another project, and now the original document stopped working:

[image: error code]

Here is the code of "packages.tex" below - I would be glad if you could help me since this is a very important project:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
    \selectlanguage{french}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, mathrsfs}
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\lap{\textbullet}~~}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\usepackage[left = 2 cm, right = 2.5cm, top = 2.5cm, bottom = 2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\singlespacing

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries\scshape}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]
 \titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.4pt]}]
 \titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\itshape}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.2pt]}]
  
\usepackage{multicol}  
\newenvironment{Figure}
  {\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}}
  {\endminipage\par\medskip}
```

**EDIT:** This also just happened in the copyed document, even if worked 5 minutes ago...

**SECOND EDIT:** here is the code of "main.tex":

```
\include{Template/packages}

\begin{document}

\include{Template/titlepage} %%% just the code of the title page

%%% Text using Figure and multicols


\include{Template/doc end} %%% For the bibliography "biblio.bib"


\end{document}
```

Comment: You didn't provide a complete file, so it's impossible to say what can go wrong. Adding your code to a minimal but complete LaTeX code compiles with no error. Also, please don't post screenshots for error, copy-paste them with this site's formatting tools.

Comment: I see you edited your code, but its still incomplete, so it can't be compiled. A LaTeX document *must* have a `document` environment (hence my request for a *complete* file).

Comment: That error has no sense... I compiled my code twice without changing the code right now, once the error the other one none !

Comment: how do I add a zip-file ?

Comment: Respectfully, if you want people to help you, provide the necessary information so that they can reproduce the problem : complete LaTeX file, which compiler, which LaTeX distribution... Again, on my computer, your code works fine once I add a `document` environment, so the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: I guess I'm not enough familiar with Overleaf to find all those informations... Thanks anyway

Comment: You didn't mention that you were using Overleaf. Also, you still haven't added a `document` environment in your file. So, just to be sure: is such an environment present in your original file?

Comment: I start the code of "main.tex" by "\begin{document}", so I think so. I add the document "main.tex" to my post.

Comment: you can not use `\include` in the preamble so the input is incorrect even if sometimes you avoid an error.  Use `\input` (I would also put the `\documenclass` command in your main document not in the input one but latex doesn't care which way you do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can not use `\include` in the preamble so the input is incorrect even if sometimes you avoid an error.  Use `\input` (I would also put the `\documenclass` command in your main document not in the input one but latex doesn't care which way you do that).

the error is because you ran latex on `packages.tex` not on your main file. Probably because overleaf guessed that packages.tex was the main file as it has `\documentclass`.